# Passing strings to a struct in C

Tags: c, string, struct, argv

I'm trying to do something simple in C that is passing 2 names (from argv[]) to a structure.
I feel like I'm all over the place with this.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name1;
    char *name2;

}names;

void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[]){
    char* buff;

    buff = malloc(strlen(n1)*sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(buff, n1);
    c->name1 = buff;
    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;

    buff = malloc(strlen(n2)*sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(buff, n2);
    c->name2 = buff;
    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    names card;
    writeNames(&card,argv[1],argv[2]);
    printf("%s %s\n",card.name1,card.name2);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is what I get:

```
naming.c: In function ‘main’:
naming.c:31:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘writeNames’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  writeNames(&card,argv[1],argv[2]);
  ^
naming.c:12:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[]){
      ^
naming.c:31:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘writeNames’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  writeNames(&card,argv[1],argv[2]);
  ^
naming.c:12:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[]){
      ^
```

I don't really undertand what is going on.

Comment: Why do you free the buffer before you're done with it? It's still holding the string, and you haven't copied the string anywhere else.

Comment: Remember that `free()` doesn't free the *pointer*, it frees the block of memory it points at.  So if you're not done with the block of memory yet (like when you're still accessing it through a different pointer), don't free it yet.

Comment: when using argc and argv[],  1) always reference both parameters, otherwise the compiler will output a warning message for each unreference parameter.    2) always check that argc indicates the parameters exist before referencing the parameters via argv[].  Otherwise, such a reference to the non-existent parameter(s) will result in a seg fault event.    When not enough parameters entered on the command line, output a 'usage' message and exit the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c->name1 = buff;
```

After this line, `c->name1` and `buff` have the same value.

```
free(buff);
```

Since `c->name1` and `buff` are equal, this is equivalent to `free(c->name1)`, which clearly is not what you want.

Also, change

```
void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[]){
```

to

```
void writeNames(names* c ,char const n1[], char const n2[]){
```

Comment: So should I write `buff=NULL` and THEN free the buffer with `free(buff)` ?

Comment: Ok. I did what you told me and it worked. But I have the feeling that there must be an easier and more "elegant" way to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: That would do the same thing as `free(NULL)`, which does nothing. Why are you trying to free the thing that holds the string while you still need the thing to hold the string?

Comment: Why not just `c->name1 = strdup(n1);`?

Comment: `strdup()` is not standard C.   It is a POSIX function, which is something else.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code:

```
void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[]){
    char* buff;

    buff = malloc(strlen(n1)*sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(buff, n1);
    c->name1 = buff;
    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;

    buff = malloc(strlen(n2)*sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(buff, n2);
    c->name2 = buff;
    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;
}
```

is nonsence.

The reason is that c->name1 and c->name2 are pointers, but not pointed to anything in particular.

This line:

```
c->name2 = buff;
```

copies the address of 'buff' to the first address of c->name2

That is not what seems to be wanted.

always check for system errors

always cleanup memory allocations before exiting

sizeof( char ) is always 1 so has no effect on the malloc

suggest:

```
void writeNames(names* c ,char n1[], char n2[])
{
    c->name1 = malloc(strlen(n1) +1);
    if( NULL == c->name1 )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for name1 failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    strcpy(c->name1, n1);


    c->name2 = malloc(strlen(n2) +1);
    if( NULL == c->name2 )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for name2 failed");
        free( c->name1 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    strcpy(c->name2, n2);
} // end function: writeNames
```